# Why does every installer on Windows have to be run with elevated privileges?

Tags: windows, installer

The current tendency to ship even the smallest applications (like simple games, tools, etc.) as a [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (.msi) or even with .exe that can do virtually anything is very annoying. After the application is installed it is run as standard user, but it is useless if during installation it can do what it wants.

For example, configuring a firewall, maybe I do not want my new shiny 15 KB calculator application to have full access to the Internet (for incoming connections :) )

Custom actions inside Windows Installer installer files are even worse, since it is possible to run a custom function inside the provided DLL file!

How do you manage to handle this, just ignore problem, or maybe have some unknown for me methods of running Windows Installer packages? And from the other side, why on Earth is everybody making installers? In many many cases, a simple [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file will be enough, at least as a opportunity to a standard installer.

Comment: Be Afraid! Its because they are doing something they aren't supposed to be doing.

Comment: you do know that pretty much all installers on all other platforms also require elevated privileges? Apart from that, some installer files can be extracted with 7zip and the likes, I find myself trying that often: I'm all for portable versions.

Comment: @stijn, mind listing that "all other platforms"?

Comment: @stjin: no, they don't.  Ordinary Unix/Linux users can install applications with no problem,

Comment: I'm not that epxerienced, but afaik on debian a normal user cant just run 'apt-get install' nor start/stop services, idem for gentoo but there the command is 'emerge' or so. And when running the typical Mac OSX installers ther's alwasy a box asking the user to grant the installer elevated permissions, no?

Comment: @stijn I assume kevin was referring to `./configure --prefix=/home/me/somewhere && make && make install`.

Comment: @Marco fair point, but we're talking installers here, not just copying files to a directory, and imo the (sometimes quite horrible) days of compiling everyhting from source are almost over; since linux popularity is slowly rising there's a ton of linux users out there that even don't know such commands.

Comment: @kevincline ordinary Unix/Linux users can do *per-user* installs, but *per-machine* still requires elevation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you need elevated privileges has to do with a per-machine install.  If you were doing a correct per-user install, you would not need elevated privileges. So this is an education/learning issue with the developers of the small applications and the end users, as they all expect to need to run installs at elevated privileges. Only installations that need to be used by all users should install as per machine on Windows Vista and above.

Some more per-user information is in *[Per-user Installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Answer (score 8):

It's the result of many system paradigms and conventions being a result of Windows' origin as a single-user environment.

People make installers because that's the way it's been done for years and people expect it. Programs go into C:\Program Files because that's the way it's been done for years and people expect it. And so on.

Only now with a new focus and dozens of security workarounds has that convention begun to get obnoxious.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer has historically been very bad at handling packages intended to be optionally per-machine or per-user. Until Vista it was largely possible, so long as you ran with the required permissions for the option you selected, but was prone to certain problems. Anything using the so-called COM tables would register per-machine, ignoring the setting of the [ALLUSERS Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then on Vista UAC made it impossible for the common case, as either a package could be told to elevate (for the per-machine case), or not to elevate (for the per-user case), but you had to declare which it was ahead of time. Unless you disable UAC, however, a package marked not to need elevation only rarely had the permissions necessary for a per-machine install.

Finally Windows 7 has introduced a new per-user paradigm built off of per-user locations and the new [MSIINSTALLPERUSER Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This corrects both the COM table per-machine registration to a per-user registration, and the UAC elevation problem. It will be interesting to see what the up-take of this property is, as it can be more difficult to write an application correctly to handle both installation scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Elevated privileges may be required to, for example, access the registry, write to the Program Files directory, or register COM objects and services.

The requirement of those privileges depends on the system's group policies, user ownership and permissions for various directories, and the access level of the user (e.g., Administrator vs. Limited User).

Installers make it convenient to install programs for inexperienced users, or to simplify the complex tasks of setting up needed DLLs, COM objects, and registry entries.

MSI files can also be invoked automatically with a script in unattended installations, again simplifying the process of installation of software.

Comment: Don't forget automatic rollbacks due to failures in the installation process and easy uninstall.

Comment: Btw., why people are still writing programs that use that horrible registry thing?

Comment: @SK-logic: Because they don't know better.

Comment: @grey and @sk-logic... could also be becasue it works.

Comment: @SK-logic, because the registry is the proper place to *register* the location of apps (get it, 'regist-ry'?), and where you integrate with the shell (file associations and such), and where you register components that provide functionality to other applications.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. For all this actions installer do not need elevated privileges. Of course "system" have to check if user that started installation have rights to install that, but again installation package itself didn't need to have special rights it is enough that installation service have needed privileges.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, the tragedy of the registry is that Microsoft has provided a nuanced and sophisticated infrastructure, but far too many programers use it as a garbage can. Need a persistent setting? Bang, into HKLM it goes, far too much trouble to look in HKCU. It also creates a bizarre coupling between all your applications: the install of your Justin Bieber fan club app corrupts the registry, and the next thing you know, your SQL Server won't boot.

Comment: @Charles, people do misuse it, but that has no bearing on my comment.  People misuse javascript too, that doesnt mean its not a good idea.  If you want to integrate with the shell, or do some of the other things I mentioned, you have to use the registry.  Its just what the OS requires.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, something that is writeable only with a superuser rights can't be called a "proper place" for storing any kind of configuration. A good old Unix-way with its configuration files is much more flexible. Registry should have been abolished ages ago, it was an extremely stupid architectural decision. It was an awful idea from the very beginning.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, but look at other OS that don't use a central registry, OS X and Linux for example. It may seem annoying to have a thousand little configuration files scattered over your file system, but you avoid the single point of failure, so at least the fan club app won't kill the database.

Comment: @SK-logic, good or bad architecture is irrelevant.  Unless you happen to be the Windows product manager for Microsoft, the registry exists whether you like it or not, and its the place to do the things I mentioned.

Comment: @Charles, Windows uses the registry for the things I mentioned.  Its not MY doing.  Its just the way they designed it.  You can point at other OS's all day long, but the registry is still going to be here, and still going to be the place for the tasks I described.  If you want to 'register' a COM component, its done in the registry - whether you like it or not.  Its where Windows looks.  I dont know what you think you are trying to persuade me into believing here - I wasnt offering subjective opinion on what the registry was used for, I was saying what it is actually used for.

Comment: @GrandMasterB, good point. I've gone far afield from the original question and your comment.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, there are certain things you can do with the registry only. Most of the little programms that OP is talking about won't ever need any of that. Installing .NET DLLs into GAC, registering COM components, etc. - you can easily live without it.

Comment: @SK, you asked why people are using that horrible registry thing.  You've now answered it for yourself:  *there are certain things you can do with the registry only*.  I dont know why this is a debate - no one's advocated sticking tons of useless info into it, and everyone knows it gets abused.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, the OPs question was specifically about "simple games, tools, etc.". And it is still unanswered. If that simple packages can be easily installed without dirtying the registry, why .msi? Why elevated rights?

Comment: @SK-logic You do not need elevated rights to write to the User registry, The actual issue is that most of the people writing the installers are not willing to take the time to learn how to do this kind of install correctly as a per user install.

Answer (score 2):

When I create an installer for an application, I can't know how the user intends to use it.  I don't know if they want to install it for every user to use, or only the installing user.  If an application is to be used by all users, then it must be installed in a location that is accessible by all users, and you need to install program shortcuts in locations that all users can access.  This requires elevated privileges.

Click-once deployment allows single-user non-elevated installation, so not all installs require priviledged access, but in general, you have to design your installers to appeal to the lowest common denominator, which will be access by all users.

Answer (score 0):

Installers have to be run with elevated privileges because the `/Program Files` and `/Windows` directories require administrator rights for changes to be made to them.  This is so that when you open an email attachment called 'I love you' and it turns out to be a trojan, you'll get warned if it tries to wipe out your operating system (or open a port, or do other dangerous things).

You don't need an installer, obviously, and software can run just fine outside the program files directory.  But consider that while you, a person posting on *programmers*, may have no problem manipulating files and directories to manually install an application with multiple files, 90% of the world *does* have a problem doing such tasks.  So installers are created.

Comment: Or, perhaps they think it is boring and something they really don't want to spend their time on, and with all those smart technologies and stuff the things should be smart enough to figure things out on their own.

Comment: I do not agree. MSI installer make changes inside program files with use of service(demon). This service can easily control if installer want only to make changes into it's own folders or not and react if something looks strange with additional question for user...

Comment: .msi files are not executables the way self-contained installers (ie, setup.exe) are.  They are packages of files that are opened by a 'trusted' service, Windows Installer.  There is no need to prompt for elevation because Windows Installer isnt going to email a virus to 10 million people when it loads a .msi file.

Comment: The trouble is that far too many Windows programmers use elevated privileges entirely gratuitously. The put icons on the shared desktop when they could just put them on the user's desktop. They write settings in HKLM when there is no reason they couldn't go in HKCU. They could put the executables in the user's directory tree, but they insist on putting them in the system directories. Even worse they hard code stuff to "C:\Program Files" even though there has been an API to find where programs should be installed since Winodws 3.1. As far as I can tell it's all just laziness.

Comment: @Charles, ok, so there are incompetent developers out there.  Tell us something we all dont know.  What does that have to do with the fact that /Program Files and /Windows need (in a restricted setting) administrator rights for changes to be made to them?

Comment: Chrome for example pretends it's on a Mac and installs into AppData\Local

Comment: @Martin, Chrome can be wiped out then by any application with normal user rights.  Chrome also, btw, writes to the registry.  Open reg-edit and search for 'Chrome'.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, but who says all programs have to go in Program Files or Windows? You certainly shouldn't be writing to Windows unless you are installing some sort of system extension/dll, and  most applications aren't doing that. Program Files is certainly the right place to put applications that are shared by all users on a system, but if you are the only person using an application why shouldn't it go in your directory tree? The OP's question was "Why (does) every installer have to be run with elevated priveleges?". My answer is programmer carelessness and lack of flexibility.

Comment: @Charles, I clearly state in my answer that apps dont need to go there (*"...and software can run just fine outside the program files directory"*).  MS recommends that practice because PF requires elevated rights to change files within it, making it more difficult for virii and trojans to infect applications.  If a virus attempts to infect other executables, you will get a UAC prompt, alerting you to the change.  This is in response, btw, to years of the programmer community screaming bloody murder about Windows security, and demanding it.  But if you want to install somewhere else, go nuts.

Comment: @GrandmasterB doesn't the msi codesigning check that an exe hasn't changed since it was installed?